Signer added when using has_one
When using the former instead of the latter, an extra signer requirement is added, even though only admin is declared as a signer:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SomeIx<'info> {
    #[account(
        has_one = admin
    )]
    pub some_struct: AccountLoader<'info, SomeStruct>,

    #[account(
        mut,
    )]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,

instead of
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SomeIx<'info> {
    pub some_struct: AccountLoader<'info, SomeStruct>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        address = some_struct.load()?.admin,
    )]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,

But the former is much more ergonomic from an IDL perspective, because the admin key is simply implied from group and can be omitted in program.methods:
        {
          "name": "admin",
          "writable": true,
          "signer": true,
          "relations": [
            "someStruct"
          ]
        },

Can we get the benefits of an idl with a related key for admin like above, without forcing this additional key to sign?

Without the Signer check has_one doesn`t really make much sense since someone could just pass in any account in the transaction and make your check work.

The answer is actually on the TS side. If you are sending the tx from some specific user like so:
const program = workspace.someProgram as Program<SomeProgram>;

    await admin.userProgram.provider.sendAndConfirm(
      new Transaction().add(
        await someIx(program, args)
        })
      )
    );

and your ix is built like:
export const someIx = (
  program: Program<SomeProgram>,
  args: Whatever
) => {
  const ix = program.methods
    .someIx()
    .accounts({
      someStruct: args.someStruct
      // admin: args.admin, // implied
    })
    .instruction();

  return ix;
};

then when Anchor implies your arguments, it uses the provider's program and key, adding it as a signer. Instead, use:
const program = workspace.someProgram as Program<SomeProgram>;

    await admin.userProgram.provider.sendAndConfirm(
      new Transaction().add(
        await someIx(admin.userProgram, args)
        })
      )
    );


In Solana's Anchor framework, the has_one constraint enforces that the specified admin key in the SomeStruct account matches the provided admin signer, but it also implicitly marks some_struct as requiring a signature due to the account verification that happens. This is likely the reason you're seeing an additional signer requirement when using the has_one constraint.
Unfortunately, as of now, using has_one in Anchor to enforce a relationship while bypassing the extra signer requirement isn’t directly supported. However, there are a few workarounds you could try:

Remove the has_one Constraint and Use Explicit Validation Logic
You can omit the has_one constraint and instead verify the relationship manually within the instruction handler function. This allows you to have a lighter IDL and avoid the extra signer requirement:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SomeIx<'info> {
    pub some_struct: AccountLoader<'info, SomeStruct>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        address = some_struct.load()?.admin,
    )]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,
}

pub fn handler(ctx: Context<SomeIx>) -> Result<()> {
    let some_struct = ctx.accounts.some_struct.load()?;
    require_keys_eq!(some_struct.admin, ctx.accounts.admin.key(), SomeError);
    Ok(())
}

This way, you don’t need the has_one constraint, and you manually enforce the admin relationship without Anchor enforcing an extra signer on some_struct.

Use a Helper Function to Verify the Admin Key in the Instruction Handler
Another option is to create a helper function that verifies the admin key for your SomeStruct account without requiring the has_one constraint in Anchor, enabling the IDL to reflect the simplified relationship:
pub fn verify_admin(some_struct: &SomeStruct, admin: &Pubkey) -> Result<()> {
    if some_struct.admin != *admin {
        return Err(SomeError.into());
    }
    Ok(())
}

pub fn handler(ctx: Context<SomeIx>) -> Result<()> {
    verify_admin(&ctx.accounts.some_struct.load()?, ctx.accounts.admin.key)?;
    Ok(())
}


Submit a Feature Request
If this is a crucial part of your workflow and you’d like the convenience of the IDL setup, you could submit a feature request to the Anchor development team for a constraint that verifies relationships without adding signer requirements. This is a common pain point, so it’s possible they may add more flexible constraints in future updates.


Currently, the best approach is likely the first or second option, as they provide the behaviour you need without adding signer constraints, while keeping your code clear and easy to maintain.

(1) is not accurate
